# Missing page number

Tags: page-numbering

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage\[hmarginratio=2:2\]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{\textbf{General Review}}\label{cp1}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Introduction}


According to T. Smith And B. Smith (2001), survival analysis is a collection of statistical approach for analyzing data, for which the outcome variable is the time until an event of interest occurs. At first, the event of interest was death and therefore the term "survival analysis" was introduced.  In the analysis, the subject will be followed until death. Today, the uses in the survival analysis vary quite a bit. Applications now include time until onset of disease, time until stock market crash, time until equipment failure, time until earthquake and so on. The time to event or survival time can be measured in years, months, weeks, days, minutes, or seconds.\\

Clark, Bradburn, Love, and Altman (2003) proposed that censoring makes survival analysis different. The difficulties of survival analysis are mainly due to the fact that only some individuals have experienced the event of interest and therefore survival times for a subset of the study group will be unknown. This phenomenon is called censoring. In general, the feature of censoring means that special methods of analysis are needed. \\


According to Efron and Tibshirani  (1994), an interval estimate is often more useful than just a point estimate. The point estimate is our best guess of the true value of the parameter, while the interval estimate is an interval of numbers around the point estimate, within which the parameter value is believed to fall with a certain degree of confidence. Standard errors are often used to assign approximate confidence intervals to a parameter of interest. There are many techniques for constructing confidence interval. The most common method is Wald method and other methods including Likelihood ratio and bootstrap. 

\section{Research Objectives}    

The objectives of this research:
\end{document}
```

Why certain page number are missing? I attached the code until second page with first page number missing.
[image]

Comment: also you should never need font commands in a heading `\chapter{\textbf{General Review}}`  chapter headings are usually bold anyway and if you are using a class where that is not the case, better to customise the class setting rather than put font commands inline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the page number of the first page is missing, then this is correct, because
this is the result of

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Remove it, if you do not want this. The default for the first page of a chapter of class `report` is page style `plain` that puts the page number at the bottom of the page.